# Winsock sends additional data

Tags: c++, sockets, client-server, winsock, send

I'm writing a small client/server application in c++ with winsock and I can't explain a few things that are happening.. 
I wrote 2 basic functions that send/receive all the data through a TCP connection..

```
bool sending(SOCKET source, char* buff, int size, int flags = 0)
{
    int sent = 0;
    int totalst = 0;
    int total = size;
    while(totalst != total)
    {
        sent = send(source, buff+totalst, size-totalst, flags);
        if(sent > 0)
        {
            totalst += sent;
        }
        if(sent == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            return false;
        }       
    }   
    return true;
}

bool receive(SOCKET source, char* buff, int size, int flags = 0)
{
    int rec = 0;
    int totalrc = 0;
    int total = size;
    while(totalrc != total)
    {
        rec = recv(source, buff+totalrc, size-totalrc, flags);
        if(rec > 0)
        {
            totalrc += rec;
        }
        if(rec == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The server sends out an integer that contains the size of the data block that will follow it.. This size of the data block in my case shouldn't change, it should always be 92600 bytes, but sometimes the client receives 92604 bytes instead. The odd thing is that if I make the server wait after sending the bock size and the block itself(with Sleep) it always sends what I would expect..

```
int i=0;                    
while(i < 100)
{
    i++;
    dat = getData();                                
    len = sizeof(dat);
    sending(source, (char*)&len, sizeof(len));
    sending(source, dat, len);
    Sleep(200);    
}
```

Can it bee that the client receives the incorrect value of bytes because of lag ?
Is there any way of fixing this?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You've already accepted an answer. But I just pointed out two bugs in your code that are likely related to what you are seeing as result of what todda is talkinga about.  See my answer below.

Comment: Thank you!Yes, nos already pointed that out in a comment but he removed it shortly after.. I just forgot to update my question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
char *x = "!";
send(socket, x, 1); // destination, buffer, size
send(socket, x, 1);
send(socket, x, 1);
send(socket, x, 1);
```

What do you expect to happen here?

```
char buffer[4];
recv(socket, buffer, 4); // source, buffer, size
```

In practice, the data sent by four `send`'s can be received into one `recv`. You don't have any guarantee that if you make `n` calls to `send` you will make `n` calls to `recv` to recieve all the data.

As nos has commented, TCP doesn't implement message boundaries. That's your job, on the application layer. Winsock doesn't send additional data, you do.

Comment: It's one of the biggest mistakes developers make with sockets - that is to assume that recv() will deliver the data in the same chunking blocks from which the client called "send". A lot of time it just seems to work this way and often code gets deployed like this - and that creates subtle bugs when it starts running in different environments.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in both your sending and receiving function.

You properly keep track of the total bytes sent/received so that you propertly exit your loop, but you forget to adjust the value of "buff" and "size" in subsequent calls to send/recv. If the buffer to send has to get transmitted with multiple calls to send, you'll send the wrong data.

Likewise, if multiple calls to "recv" are needed, you'll overwrite the data copied at the start of the buffer.

It should read:

```
sent = send(source, buff+totalst, size-totalst, 0);
```

Likewise for the recv case:

```
rec = recv(source, buff + totalrc, size-totalrc, 0);
```

I'm not sure if this is causing your issue, but I have a feeling when the scenario pointed out by todda is true, then your data streams are getting corrupted by this bug.

Make sense?  Also, you should be prepared to handle the case where recv() will return 0.

I hope this helps.